# Parsing 2 Arrays to friend function

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having troubles by accessing 2 of my arrays at the same time with my friend function.

Here is my code (the important part):

```
int main(){
 // Array with fracture, example 3/4
 cFracture cFArr[8] = {cFracture(3,4), cFracture(24,6)};
 // One fracture have to be added to other
 // I am missing something here ->
 add(cFArr[0]); 
 return 0;
}
```

I need to understand, how to parse 2 Arrays at the same time.
Here is my add function, here is nothing in, i need to understand how to get 2 arrays at the same time...

```
int add(cFracture add_f){
 cout << "Result after adding fracture 1 to fracture 2: " << add_f.a << "/" << add_f.b << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

And here is my class:

```
cFracture{
   int a;
   int b;
 public:
   cFracture(int a_in = 0, int b_in = 0){
     a = a_in;
     b = b_in;
   }

 friend int add(cFracture add_f);
};
```

How should I go on? How to get 2 arrays at the same time, so i can add one to the other? It have to be done with friend function.

Comment: @DiegoAmicabile sorry, was the translation mistake. Should be cFracture.

Comment: Can't you just define the function `int add(cFracture add_f1, cFracture add_f2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another argument to the function.

```
int add(cFracture add_f1, cFracture add_f2){
 cout << "Result after adding fracture 1 to fracture 2: " << add_f1.a + add_f2.a << "/" << add_f1.b + add_f2.b << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

and change the `friend` declaration to match the new function.

```
cFracture{
   int a;
   int b;
 public:
   cFracture(int a_in = 0, int b_in = 0){
     a = a_in;
     b = b_in;
   }

 friend int add(cFracture, cFracture);
};
```

Then you can do:

```
add(cFarr[0], cfArr[1]);
```

in the `main()` function.

Comment: This worked! Only one thing is missing in your answer, i had to add cFracture add_f2 in my class too (friend int add(cFracture add_f1, cFracture add_f2);)